# re.search() breaks for key in form.keys() loop

Tags: python

Perhaps I am just crazy or missing something really basic.  Why would this happen?

If I use this url

index.cgi?mode=pos&pos_mode=checkout&0_name=Shampoo&0_type=Product&0_price=4.50&0_qty=1&0_total=4.50

which runs this code

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

for key in form.keys()
    print key

    if re.search("name", key):
        print "Found name."
```

The result prints

```
mode
```

If I remove the re.search() it prints all the keys.  Why?

I searched stackoverflow and google before I posted but I didn't come up with anything. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you getting an exception?  Check your server logs.  Have you done:

```
import re
```

at the top of the script?  Try wrapping the code in `try` / `except`.

Comment: Wow... :-(  I feel 10x stupid.  Not a good first post to stackoverflow...

I forgot to import re.  I was using cgitb and I thought it threw an error when I forgot to import something.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @RogueFalcon:  Welcome to SO!  We all hope you enjoy your time here.  There is absolutely no use in feeling stupid.  Think of it this way:  you'll probably never make this mistake again :)

Comment: I almost got it, but your answer was more insightful :))

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you get an error? Try checking types of all keys or anything you suspect could be wrong.